# How do I store the first value in a c++ dice game and compare it in the next move?

Tags: c++, dice

I am currently working on a dice game. Where The user rolls a pair of dice first, so lets say he rolled and Dice 1 = 2 and Dice 2 = 3. So the total is 5 now. Now, he needs to get 5 (total) again in order to win, if he didnt get 5 in his next move then he rolls again and the game continues. But he looses if at any point of time, he rolled a total of two.

So,please tell me how do I store value of the first roll and compare it with the next move(s). I tried something, but it does not seem to work.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<ctime>      // for the time() function
#include<cstdlib>    // for the srand() and rand() functions
using namespace std;

// Declare variables
//int compInput;
int userInput;
int die1 = 0;
int die2 = 0;
int dieTotal = 0;
int Dice ()
{
    // roll the first die
    die1 = (rand() % 6 ) + 1;
    // roll the second die
    die2 = (rand() % 6 ) + 1;


}

// iniating a second two pair dice function.
int compDice()

{
    Dice();
    dieTotal = die1 + die2;
    return (dieTotal);
}



// User Rolling the dice and calucalting the total here

int userGame()
{
    cout << "\nUser turn --- Press 2 to roll" << endl;
    cin >> userInput;

    if ( userInput == 2 )
    {
        Dice ();
        cout << "\nThe user rolled        Dice 1 = " << die1 << " and Dice 2 = " << die2 << endl;
        cout << "Total = " << die1 + die2 << endl;
    }

    else {
        cout << "Wrong input.";
        //userGame();
    }
    return (die1 + die2 );
}

int checkForWin ()
{
    while (true)
    {

        int result1 = compDice();
        int result = userGame();

        // int finalResult = dieTotal;
        if (result == result1 )
        {
            cout << "\nUser won. Computer looses....m " << endl;
            break;
        }

        else if (result == 2)
        {
            cout << "\nUser looses. Computer won." <<endl;
            break;
        }

        else
        {
        }
    }
}

// Calling for the checkForWin() function in main and the srand.
int main ()
{
    cout << "This is the Dice game. " << endl;

    // set the seed
    srand(time(0));
    checkForWin(); // Initiating the game.
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: elaborate on what didn't work

Comment: You seem to have the correct idea here, but you're comparing what the user gets against what the computer gets. The easy way is to do basically the same thing, but have the user roll twice.

Comment: I've just compiled it myself and it works, albeit that Dice and checkForWin need to return a value, or be declared void.

Comment: i thought I was doing that in compDice() ? its for compareDice...isnt that right?

Comment: umm, i think converting to void is a good idea for them. I was thinking of having four varibale die1, die2, die3, die4 ?

Comment: Yes the program works but not in the expected way... i think it replaces the values of die1 die2 when run the second time (Dice())..?

Comment: @user15169 Yes, the values of die1 and die2 get replaced. It's not clear what you were expecting, because it doesn;t seem like that would impact your results in this case.

Comment: @zdan, i just want the first roll to stored and compare it with the next rolls so that i can find the winner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After our comment chat/misunderstandings, I've taken the liberty of copying your code and modifying it (as little as possible to maintain your coding style - I would not recommend this style for any future projects) to produce the results you want. Let me know if it works (simple testing showed it worked, may have missed some other quirks)

```
#include<iostream>
#include<ctime>      // for the time() function
#include<cstdlib>    // for the srand() and rand() functions
using namespace std;

// Declare variables
//int compInput;
int userInput;
int firstRoll = 1;
int die1 = 0;
int die2 = 0;
int dieTotalToMatch = 0;
void Dice ()
{
    // roll the first die
    die1 = (rand() % 6 ) + 1;
    // roll the second die
    die2 = (rand() % 6 ) + 1;

}

// iniating a second two pair dice function.
void compDice()
{
    Dice();
    dieTotalToMatch = die1 + die2;
}



// User Rolling the dice and calucalting the total here

int userGame()
{
    cout << "\nUser turn --- Press 2 to roll" << endl;
    cin >> userInput;

    if ( userInput == 2 )
    {
        Dice ();
        cout << "\nThe user rolled        Dice 1 = " << die1 << " and Dice 2 = " << die2 << endl;
        cout << "Total = " << die1 + die2 << endl;
    }

    else {
        cout << "Wrong input.";
        //userGame();
    }
    return (die1 + die2 );
}

void checkForWin ()
{

    while (true)
    {

        int result = userGame();
        if (firstRoll)
        {
            dieTotalToMatch = result;
            firstRoll = 0;
            continue;
        }
        // int finalResult = dieTotal;
        if (result == dieTotalToMatch )
        {
            cout << "\nUser won. Computer looses....m " << endl;
            break;
        }

        else if (result == 2)
        {
            cout << "\nUser looses. Computer won." <<endl;
            break;
        }

        else
        {
        }
    }
}

// Calling for the checkForWin() function in main and the srand.
int main ()
{
    cout << "This is the Dice game. " << endl;

    // set the seed
    srand(time(0));
    checkForWin(); // Initiating the game.
    cin.ignore();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: remove it from answer and put it as a comment.

Comment: @user15169 sorry? didn't catch that

Comment: thanks for the reply. If you notice

if (result == result1 )
I am comparing it. But it not fucntioning right. For example if the total come out 6 for the first move and when the user gets 6 again, the game moves on. Instead he should be shown with the "you won ...." message.

Comment: here is the output, http://pastebin.com/Q0pfGGrN . See that the first roll total was 8. But when 8 came the next time, it just continued with the game..

Comment: @user15169 oh wooow, so you don't want to compare the current roll with the previous roll, but ALL previous rolls?! That is a very different problem than the one you were stating you had. We can still do it though, but please confirm that that is the result you want (An 8 was rolled, then 10 rolls later, another 8. That ends the game?)

Comment: No. I understand finally. Only the first roll is stored. After that, you want to check against the first roll. Got it. Gimme two minutes.

Comment: well, the no matter what the first roll is (8, 10, 12, etc etc). it should be stored and considered a winning number and then should be checked with the next rolls. if the winning number comes after 25 rolls, then it should say you won, and if it comes even after 5 rolls, then also it should say you won. That means, first roll should be checked against all the next rolls.

thanks so much :)

Comment: awesome it works now...thanks so so so much. I will improvise on this now. thanks I am new to c++, but it has started making sense now.